# Nativescript Clickable span color in Android

Tags: nativescript

I have a Nativescript app (Android) where I am creating a Clickable span that is nested within a text paragraph.  The goal is to display the span in a green color and when clicked to redirect them to a different location.  Here is my code:

```js
var color = '#3aba90';
if (textview.android) {
  var ss = new android.text.SpannableString(text);
  var ClickableSpanClass = android.text.style.ClickableSpan.extend({
   onClick: function (view) {
    func.redirectToSite(true);
   },
   updateDrawState: function (tp) {
    this.super.updateDrawState(tp);
    tp.setColor(color);
    tp.setUnderlineText(false);
   }
  });
  var clickablespan = new ClickableSpanClass();
  ss.setSpan(clickablespan, 356, 386, 33);
  textview.android.setText(ss);
       textview.android.setMovementMethod(android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the span does not render in the green color I selected.  I tried also 0x3aba90ff, green, and other variations of the color variable, but I cannot make it render in the correct color.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the solution was very simple:

I was trying to pass a regular color string (#3aba90) to an android native API call.  So, as soon as changed:

**tp.setColor(color);**

to

**tp.setColor(new colorModule.Color(color).android);**

everything worked.  Of course, make sure that you have the colorModule imported:

**var colorModule = require("color");**

NOTE:  Thank you Nikolay Iliev from Telerik for this solution.

Comment: For everyone interested in the full implementation for both Android and iOS: https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/others/clickableSpanIOSAndroid

Comment: Nikolay, one note on your example.  In the iOS implementation, you are changing the colors of the "hot zone" text, but it would not respond to user taps.  There are no links defines for those zones.